# How to read config file in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm creating a new pipeline job, before execute detail bat files, there are lots of  variable to define.

```
node('BuildMachine')
{
  env.ReleaseNumber='1.00.00'
  env.BuildType='Test'
  env.Language='ENU'
  ...

  Stage('Build')
  {
    bat '''
      call build.bat %ReleaseNumber%_%BuildType%_%BUILD_NUMBER%
      '''
  }
}
```

1. Can I save these global variable to a config file, store in git repository and read it?
2. Can these variable still work in bat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) Plugin aka (Environment Injector Plugin) gives you several options to set and use environment variables in Jenkins job.
It will write the variables to a file which can be loaded later to get the variables, but I don't think the variables will directly work in bat.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to define the variables in every build, you could (because the Jenkinsfile is actually just Groovy) define variables and use them in the call as command line arguments:

```
 node('BuildMachine') {
    def releaseNumber='1.00.00'
    def buildType='Test'
    def language='ENU'

    Stage('Build')
    {
      bat "call build.bat ${releaseNumber}_${buildType}_%BUILD_NUMBER%"
    }
  }
```

I assume that BUILD_NUMBER is a environment variable set before starting the build job. Otherwise you could do it like the others. Note that the double quotation marks instead of the single quotation marks are necessary for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is that you define a < key > = < value > file and then you can do:

```
readFile "<your config file>"
configData = file.split("\n")
    configData.each {
      lineData = it.split("=")
      switch(lineData[0].toLowerCase().trim()){
        case "<key 1>": <varName 1> = lineData[1].trim(); break;
        case "<key 2>": <varName 2> = lineData[1].trim(); break;
        case "<key 3>": <varName 3> = lineData[1].trim(); break;
....
      }
    }
```

And then use the varName to call the bat as you mentioned

The advantage with this code is that you don't depend on the order of the contents of the config file